# @Scheduled in spring boot does not trigger method

Tags: java, spring-boot, scheduling

I have a Spring Boot application and I want to trigger the execution of a method using @Scheduled. I added the @EnableScheduling annotation in the main class (also tried with a config class), but it seems not to work.
My code is:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableScheduling
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

```
@Component
public class FOApp {

    @Autowired
    CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @Autowired
    OptionsController optionsController;

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 51 * * * ?")
    public void runFOApp() throws InterruptedException {

        List<Customer> initialLoad = customerRepository.getInitialLoad();

        for (int i = 0; i < initialLoad.size(); i++) {

            optionsController.get(initialLoad.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: At what time you are expecting to schedule this ?

Comment: Are you FOApp class and Application  class in same package.Is Application scanning the FoApp bean?

Comment: 51 minutes past the hour

Comment: they are in same package, but I also tried to add a component scan with the name of the package explicitly and no results...

Comment: To troubleshoot use a cron string that causes it to run more often or create one on https://crontab.guru/

Comment: your cron will be run after 51 minutes. If you want to test it use "0 0/51 * * * ?" and it will run directly and every 51 minutes on the hour after that

Comment: I don't see a reason as to why this does not work! Can you try scheduling a simple job with just a logger to run every minute and see if that works.